# Unexpected results with a menu at different browser sizes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I have been having some of the strangest errors that I think are because of the fact that I am manipulating an element using jquery at one browser size and expecting css to pick up the slack at a different browser size.

Go here: http://jsbin.com/vipizukarobi/2

1. Resize the browser - Menu should leave (< 768px), Box with Open should appear. Click nothing.
2. Resize the browser (> 768) Box with Open should leave, menu is back.
3. Repeat step one.
4. Click Open - Watch magic.

Issues: Resize the browser with the menu open (> 768px) after clicking "open" the box with the x will go away, ok. Now resize back down, the box with the x re-appears. This should not happen, the menu should disappear. The box with "Open" should re-appear, and you should have to "start over".

- Refresh the page, shrink the browser, click open, click the x after everything finishes.
- Resize the browser.

Where is my menu. Why is the "Open" still on the page.

**Additional Issue**

Theres an additional error I cannot replicate with this fiddle, the issue is that when the x slides in, its a 32x32 box, it feels like the box slides in at 32x28 and then when  it finishes sliding it it adds the additional 4 pixels making it look like if you walked into a room sideways holding a scrunched up towel and then when you finished walking in, let the towel drop to be full length (it looks broken)

I cant replicate that here and I am using the same html, css and jquery. So it might be a conflicting library(?) - what would cause that?

Comment: the problems is that when you show and hide elements with jquery you override the normal css. trying to get the same result using only jQuery.

Comment: so whats the fix? have two menus? use javascript to detect browser resize? all of that seems wrong to me .... whats the proper way to do this? can you provide a fiddle?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here i've created a fiddle where i use ONLY jQuery (with jQueryUI, like you) to reach your goal:

http://jsfiddle.net/Monteduro/kcr08hd7/

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  menuFromSize( $(window).width(), true ); // First status
  $(window).resize(function(){
      menuFromSize( $(this).width(), false ); // Edit at every resize
  });

  $('#open-panel').click(function() {
      $('#side-panel').show('slide', {'direction': 'left'}, 500);
      $(this).hide();
      $('#close-panel').delay(500).show('slide', {'direction': 'left'}, 500);
  });

  $('#close-panel').click(function() {
      $('#side-panel').delay(500).hide('slide', {'direction': 'left'}, 500);
      $(this).hide('slide', {'direction': 'left'}, 500);
      $('#open-panel').delay(1000).show('slide', {'direction': 'left'}, 500);
  });

});

// Function that handle the resizing 
function menuFromSize(size, first_time) {

    if ( size < 768 ) {

        if ( first_time ) {

            $('#side-panel').hide();
            $('#open-panel').show();
            $('#close-panel').hide();  

        }else{

            if ( !$('#close-panel').is(':visible') ) {
                $('#side-panel').hide();
                $('#open-panel').show();
                $('#close-panel').hide();
            }

        }

    }else{

        $('#side-panel').show()
        $('#open-panel').hide();
        $('#close-panel').hide();  

     }

}
```

Comment: I'm sad that this was the selected answer, and for posterity sake truly hope that you, the current reader of this comment, do not follow the advice of the answer above. Simply use addClass() and removeClass() and use CSS to set your breakpoints... please DO NOT check the viewport width with javascript to determine how to present your navigation.

Answer (score 0):

By using jquery's animation functions (.hide(), .show()), you're directly manipulating that element's style property, which will always have more specificity than your stylesheet, so it overrides the responsive styles you have set there.

To solve this dilemma, replace the jquery animation calls with CSS animations.  Simply addClass('active'), removeClass('active').  Use whatever class you'd prefer in place of "active".  Then you can still set all the various properties needed to remain responsive.  For the animation, use the CSS "transition" property.